Add URI Request to LibCurl Post command
I am using ubuntu 22.04 and libcurl 7.81.0 to create and send onvif post command. I originally got everything working in python, but am unable to use python in the final project. Therefore I'd like to replicate the command in libcurl. My issue is not with sending commands and receiving responses.
I need more clarity on how to set the request URI in the header. When I send a post command via python using zeep, the post header is as follows in the image from wireshark:

However, when I try to send a post message inside libcurl, I get the following:

Is there a curlopt option that I'm missing to set that URI field? I really need curl to replicate exactly what was sent in python.
My curl options are set with:
curl = curl_easy_init();
std::string url = serverIP + ":" + std::to_string(serverPort);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, settings.responseTimeout_ms);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &cameraResponse);

My callback is just:
size_t writeCallback(char* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string* userp)
{
    userp->append(contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

I then create and set my header field (omitting the actual string contents from this post)
struct curl_slist* header = nullptr;
header = curl_slist_append(header, host.c_str());
header = curl_slist_append(header, agent.c_str());
header = curl_slist_append(header, acceptEncoding.c_str());
header = curl_slist_append(header, accept.c_str());
header = curl_slist_append(header, connection.c_str());
header = curl_slist_append(header, soapAction.c_str());
header = curl_slist_append(header, contentType.c_str());
header = curl_slist_append(header, contentLength.c_str());

with content just being the encoded data in a soap format that I want to send. As far as I'm aware, no problem here as well.
Then I set the last curl options and calling easy perform
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, content.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);
CURLcode curlResult = curl_easy_perform(curl);

I find that the responses using libcurl from my camera are about 2X slower than when using python. I'm assuming it has to do with the differences in the format of the message. I'd like to start with fixing the URI request as mentioned above. Would appreciate feedback on that topic.

The option you are looking for is, surprise-surprise, CURLOPT_URL. (URL is a kind of URI)

I use that above to set the ip address and port of the camera. Fo I add the URI info to end of that or in place of what I have done?

Your callback should take a void* not a std::string* and you should do static_cast<std::string*>(userp); to get the std::string*. It may work like you've done it, but it has undefined behavior.

Try to append the path and see what happens.

Is content URL encoded?

That is fine and an easy change. was my original function, but have been doing quite a bit of experimenting. My question was more specific to the URI field that I think @n.m. could be an AI has eluded too. I'm just in the habit of putting up code with posts since it is likely to be asked for.

content is an onvif message in soap format.


Is there a curlopt option that I'm missing to set that URI field?

You are already using it - CURLOPT_URL. You just need to specify the complete HTTP URL, not just the server's IP and port by itself:

Pass in a pointer to the URL to work with. The parameter should be a char * to a null-terminated string which must be URL-encoded in the following format:
scheme://host:port/path

Try this:
std::string url = "http://" + serverIP + ":" + std::to_string(serverPort) + "/onvif/DeviceIO";
// or "https://" if needed ...

If serverPort is the standard 80 for an HTTP url, or 443 for an HTTPS url, you can just omit it completely:
std::string url = "http://" + serverIP + "/onvif/DeviceIO";
// or "https://" if needed ...


On a side note: when using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, you do not need to send a Host header yourself, let libcurl handle that for you, based on thee URL you specify.  Also, some of the other headers you are sending manually can be handled with other libcurl options instead, such as CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, etc.

Thank you. This was helpful and got me exactly what I was looking for. n.m. could be an AI also provided the answer, but I appreciate the full explanation. My issue was really about not understanding libcurl fully. I also appreciate the other fields pointed out. I have updated my application appropriately.
